# How to run multiple .jmx recorded script at one instance on non-gui mode without Any plugin?

Tags: jmeter

I am doing Performance testing for my web App with JMeter.

I tried running multiple (more than 1) .jmx by merging all scripts in one, but it doesn't work on Jmeter non-gui mode. So is that possible to run multiple .jmx recorded scripts from Jmeter non-gui mode without using any plugins like Maven or Ant plugins? Keep in mind that all different scripts have different credentials to login into web App and executing different tasks.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions will differ depending on your operating system:

- For Unix based ([Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), [MacOSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/), etc): you can use [`GNU parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) program:

  ```
  parallel --gnu << 'EOF'
  jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result1.jtl
  jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result2.jtl
  etc.
  EOF
  ```
- For [MS Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows): you can use a CMD or Powershell script assuming [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command something like:

  ```
  start jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result1.jtl
  start jmeter -n -t test2.jmx -l result2.jtl
  etc.
  ```

---

The fastest and the easiest way will be going for [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool, you will be able to launch simultaneous different JMeter tests via simple [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) syntax:

```
---
execution:
- scenario:
    script: test1.jmx
- scenario: 
    script: test2.jmx
- scenario: 
    script: test3.jmx
    #etc
```

See [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests) for more details.

Comment: Thank you bro. This helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple thread groups in a single .jmx in sequence or parallel as per your requirement. 
For more information check [this](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-manage-test-plan/)

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you, but i need to run multiple thread on multiple .jmx. Which means one .jmx contains one thread group. And I want to run those multiple .jmx files in non-gui mode